# Archive of FedWire participants

Tags: data-request, usa, finance, bank

I'm looking for an archive of institutions that have participated in the Fed's FedWire service -- preferably back to before 2004.

The Fed hosts an [up-to-date participants list](https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/download.html), but I haven't been able to find an archive of it. Closest thing I've found is [this Github repo](https://github.com/gatepay/FedACHdir) that's been archiving a similar list of FedACH institutions for the past couple years.

Anyone got any ideas? I really hope this publicly available time-series hasn't just vanished from history.